# How to get an array that returns from a controller in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a controller named TestAsync, it returns like below:

```json
{
  "result": true,
  "payload": {
    "data": [{
        "pid": 1,
        "agent_name": "Agent 001"
      },
      {
        "pid": 2,
        "agent_name": "Agent 002"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to get the array from javascript, I tried below:

```js
ajaxCallPostWithHeaders('@Url.Action("TestAsync", "User")',
    params, headers,
    function(result) {
      if (result.result == true) {
        const agents = result.payload.data;
        alert(agents); //--> it shows ,,,,,,,,,,,,,   

        $.each(agents, function(i, e) {
            alert(e.agent_name);

          }
        }
```

what I missed?

Comment: The return value is a JSON or JS object?

Comment: it is an object

Comment: Please show us the ```console.log(result)``` in codes.

Comment: it shows

(index):168 (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]0: Array(2)0: Array(1)0: []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: this code works except missing end parens in $.each function

Comment: @Don2, please ```console.log(JSON.stringify(result))``` for us.

Comment: JSON.stringify shows:

(index):168 {"result":true,"payload":{"data":[[[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]]]]}}

Comment: @Don2, it shows that the data inside your ```data``` is empty array

Comment: I got it! .. I have to convert it into a string first in the controller before JSON. stringify but now I face the other problem.. how to show e.agent_name? 

the result is:

{"result":true, "payload":  
{ "data" : [ { "pid": 1,"agent_name":"Agent 001"  },  
{ "pid": 2, "agent_name": "Agent 002"  }
] 
}
}

Comment: @Don2 JSON is a string. The problem is when the data is passed to your function, it shows that you have a empty nested array.